# What is the difference with AES128 and AES256 regarding key expansion and byes generation? (and maybe AES192)

Tags: c++, aes

If I am not wrong, for AES128, we generate 16 bytes of data, hence the code for it is shown below.

```
void KeyExpansion(unsigned char inputKey[16], unsigned char expandedKeys[176])
{
    for(int i=0; i<16; i++)
    expandedKeys[i] = inputKey[i];

    int bytesGenerated = 16;
    int rconIteration = 1;
    unsigned char temp[4];

     while(bytesGenerated <176)
    {
        for(int i=0; i<4; i++)
        temp[i] = expandedKeys[i + bytesGenerated - 4];

        if(bytesGenerated % 16 == 0)
        {
            keyExpansionCore(temp, rconIteration);
            rconIteration++;
        }

        for(unsigned char a=0; a<4; a++)
        {
            expandedKeys[bytesGenerated] = expandedKeys[bytesGenerated - 16] ^ temp[a];
            bytesGenerated++;
        }
    }
}
```

However, I am not too sure about AES256. Do we also generate 16 bytes of data or 32 bytes of data? If it generates 32 bytes of data, I have to change my inputKey[16] to inputKey[32] instead? And what about the expandedKey? I was confused when I saw expandedKey[176] with the inputKey[16], doesn't it becomes 192 bytes? (But I saw this code while searching for a AES128.)

Answer (score 0):

It's the key size that is different, not the block size (which is always 16 bytes). The key size in AES can be 128, 192, or 256 *bits*.
[More info](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard) and also see [this](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/3615/what-is-the-effect-of-the-different-aes-key-lengths) and [this](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/31632/what-is-the-difference-between-key-size-and-block-size-for-aes) StackExchange answer.